# trasmitting data to mySQL through VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'l like to get the datetime from my PC and send it over to my table
Here it is : Failure to communicate / String was not recognized as a valid DateTime
How to make the current date so when I pass it over to my DB ?

```
  Dim regDate As Date = Date.Now()
            Dim strDate As String = regDate.ToString("MM\/dd\/yyyy")
```

SQL throws me an error if I use this :

```
SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", Convert.ToDateTime(strDate))
```

Error is :  String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

```
            Dim SqlQuery1 As String = "INSERT INTO pontaj(id_pontaj,id,prezente,data) " & _
                "VALUES (0,@Id,1,@Data)"


            Using con = New MySqlConnection("Server = localhost;Database = users; Uid=root; Pwd = password")
                Using SQLcmd = New MySqlCommand(SqlQuery1, con)
                    con.Open()
                    'SQLcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                    '  SQLcmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@Id_presence", TextBox1.Text))
                    '  SQLcmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@Id", TextBox2.Text))
                    '  SQLcmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@Hours", TextBox3.Text))
                    '  SQLcmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@Date", TextBox4.Text))


                    ' SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_presence", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text))
                    SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Convert.ToInt32(Label5.Text))
                    ' SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prezente", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text))
                     SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", Convert.ToDateTime(strDate))


                    SQLcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using


            End Using
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to convert the string back to a date, use directly the date

```
SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", DateTime.Now)
```

When using parameters, it is the framework code that presents the values to your database engine in a way that could understood as a date, number or string.

Your error is trying to convert a date in a string using a format that probably is not the default format recognized on your machine as a valid datetime.
Now, when you try to reconvert the string back to a date you get the error.
You could use something like this to remove the error

```
Dim t As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(strDate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

but there is no reason to make all these conversions

Comment: Can you help me with something else ? It's basically the same thing , I get an error :  Unknown Column Nume in 'field list'

Basically I am just trying to add some values to my table users1
 
My DB : http://prntscr.com/39on8i

vb code : http://pastebin.com/CcBFiUAN

Comment: Usually this kind of error is caused by a mistyped field name in the command text, but from your links it seems all correct.